# How to figure out which docker container is using the most resources?

Tags: docker

Using top I can see that docker is using 90%+ of my cpu usage [image]

however when I run docker stats --all
I dont see any significant cpu usage.
[image]

Is there another explanation for the high dockerd cpu usage?

Comment: Check these links https://forums.docker.com/t/dockerd-using-100-cpu/94962, https://bobcares.com/blog/docker-high-cpu-usage/

Comment: You're confusing the `dockerd` daemon process with the processes running inside a docker container.

Comment: tried out the first link and I did have some corrupt log files. we'll see if that fixes it